# Could we define two random variables such that the product of them is Normal distribution(Gaussian)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Could we find two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which $XY \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

I found the ratio of two normal distributed random variables is distributed Cauchy distribution.

However, on the other way, the product ($U=XY$) of $X \sim Cauchy()$ and $Y \sim Normal()$ is not Normal distribution.

My first question is that I could not understand why the reverse statement does not hold.

My second question is how to find $X$ and $Y$ such the product is normal distribution.
(Assume both $X$ and $Y$ are continuous.)

Comment: Let random variable $Y$ be identically $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right.
Your answer is a trivial solution. However, I would like to solve for general solutions.

Comment: For $X$, $Y$ independent, one might be able to get some insight from the moment generating function.  (This is only speculation, I have not done calculation.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you so much for your kind comment. I agree with your opinion. I will try to approach with moment generating function from now on.